# Creating a drag select screen capture in angular 7

Tags: angular7

I need to select from image on drag and get the all four cooridnates of the selection. I have found the same implemented in JS. 
[Creating a drag select screen capture for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099145/creating-a-drag-select-screen-capture-for-google-chrome)
Is there any libraries that impements the same as the below in angular 7.?

Comment: Hey Sreelakshmi, welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be awesome if you can show your progress before asking questions directly. for ex: a code block or attempts you have made to solve this problem. that way others would understand your problem and will be able to help you faster. have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Yes You have `ngx-drag-to-select`

> Reference  [ngx-drag-to-select](https://d3lm.github.io/ngx-drag-to-select/)

According to Doc Here is the example code

```
import { DragToSelectModule } from 'ngx-drag-to-select';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DragToSelectModule.forRoot({
      selectedClass: 'my-selected-item',
      shortcuts: {
        disableSelection: 'alt+meta'
      }
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: than you for the comment. But i need to crop an image and get all the four coordinates. as per my understand , the above library can not be used for this